# Constraints and implicite operators

Tags: c#, operators, constraints

I have three classes A,B and C, 
some properties are in all three classes, some not

```
public class A
{ 
    public string Firstname {get; set;}
    public string  Lastname {get; set;}
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int xxx {get; set}   // only in class A
    public int yyy{get; set}    // only in class A
    ... 
}

public class B
{ 
    public string Firstname {get; set;}
    public string  Lastname {get; set;}
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int aaa {get; set} // only in class B
    public int bbb {get; set} // only in class B
    ... 
}

public class C
{ 
    public string Firstname {get; set;}
    public string  Lastname {get; set;}
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int kkk {get; set} // only in class C
    public int ppp {get; set} // only in class C
    ...
}
```

I want to call the Execute method of class XYZ ...

```
public class XYZ
{
    public override Execute<T>() where T: Generic_T, new()
    { 
      T abc = new T();
      ...
      Debug.WriteLine(abc.Firstname + ”, “ + abc.Lastname + “, “ + abc.ID);
    }
}
```

... with all three classes,like:

```
XYZ x1 = new XYZ();
XYZ.Execute<A>();

XYZ x2 = new XYZ();
XYZ.Execute<B>();

XYZ x3 = new XYZ();
XYZ.Execute<C>();
```

My idea doesn’t work:

```
public class Generic_T
{
    public static implicit operator A(Generic_T x)
    { 
        return (A)x.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Where is the mistake?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I fixed you code a little and reformatted, but the code is not valid at all, it wont compile.  There are several mistakes, so I can say what you want answered.

Comment: Please, provide a real example. You obviously typed it right here. Copy/paste the actual code

Answer (score 2):

Mistakes:

1. What is `CloneMemberwise()` ?
2. If you meant `MemberwiseClone()`, you can't call it there. It is a `protected` member.
3. You cannot call properties on a type. Here: `T.Firstname`, `T.Lastname`, etc.
4. It is `Debug`, not `Degub`.
5. You do not pass a value/reference in to the `Execute` method.
6. Neither A, B or C derives from `Generic_T`, so the constraint on the Execute method will fail.
7. Class names do not end with `()`. You had `class A()` which I re-edited already.
8. `A` or any class cannot be automagically converted to `Generic_T`.
9. You should be using inheritance, I suspect `Generic_T` should be a base class.
10. You do not have a specific question

Possible suggestion:

```
public abstract class Generic_T
{
    public string Firstname {get; set;}
    public string  Lastname {get; set;}
    public int ID {get; set;}
}

public class A : Generic_T
{ 
    public int xxx {get; set}   // only in class A
    public int yyy{get; set}    // only in class A
    ... 
}

public class B : Generic_T
{ 
    public int aaa {get; set}   // only in class B
    public int bbb {get; set} // only in class B
    ... 
}

public class C : Generic_T
{ 
    public int kkk {get; set}   // only in class C
    public int ppp {get; set} // only in class C
    ...
}
```

Also there is not reason to convert any of the derived classes to `Generic_T` as they as an instance of `Generic_T` already.

All of this information is normally explained in most introductory texts for C#/.NET. Failure to understand them, will make your life miserable.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why do you need Generic_T in your code.
To force Execute work you need to implement following interface

```
interface IFoo 
{
   int ID {get; set;}
   string LastName {get; set;}
   string FirstName {get; set;}
}
```

Then your execute method will look like this:

```
public override Execute<T>(T obj) where T: new(), IFoo
{ 
    Debug.WriteLine(obj.Firstname + ”, “ + obj.Lastname + “, “ + obj.ID);
}
```